# My Anaconda stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

My Anaconda stopped working after I installed some packages for statistics (not entirely sure if it is related), I cannot open Jupyter Notebook or Spyder, I can only open Anaconda navigator from the Anaconda command prompt and once there, if I try to run Jupyter or Spyder I get this error message:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 20, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import aliases, flags, NotebookApp as ServerApp
File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Users\Jorge87\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py", line 5, in 
from jupyterlab.labapp import main
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 14, in 
from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .app import LabServerApp
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py", line 9, in 
from .server import ServerApp
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 26, in 
from jupyter_server.base.handlers import ( # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server'
`
```

I tried uninstalling Python and installing it again, I tried also uninstalling Anaconda and installing it again but nothing seems to work.

I also tried updating Anaconda and writing the command 'Activate Root' and then 'conda update' as I saw in other solutions in stack overflow but nothing seems to work.

I´m using Windows in case this is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

try to reinstall the jupyter_server module
 since it is the one that is giving you an error.
(I do not know if you are working on the base.)

or try to create a virtual environment and run it without anything else
(the version of python you have)

```html
conda create --name envexample python=3.7
```

There you will know if the base environment is corrupted and not the instances themselves.

or do you have another option to reinstall everything

```html
conda update --all --no-pin --no-channel-priority
```

Comment: PS: it gave me a lot of problems in windows (8.1) since the operating system kernel overprotects itself by letting some processes and threads not interfere with each other, currently I use it in linux (ubuntu) and it has not given me any problems so far .

Comment: Thank you, now I executed that line and got this:


# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate envexample
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

Comment: well apparently I think you forgot to activate the environment. if you want it to start automatically use "conda config --set auto_activate_base true" so that every time you start you do not have to write the activation of the environment

Comment: I tried the other line and got this error: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: what other line?

Comment: I need a more less information, steps you take and results of those actions.

Answer (score 1):

install jupyter_server may help

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_server
```